# one coupon - same price

Tags: coupon, coupon-codes, offers

I need to create a coupon that will make all the products in ONE category have the same price.

The prices of the products in that category are all above 200, and I would like to make a coupon that sets the price to 199 when used.

Needless to say that the products have different prices.

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if that could be possible with a cart price rule, but you can set advanced pricing for each product and set the price that you want to display. Works like a catalog price rule but is configured on catalog>products>select product>price>advanced pricing>select all customer groups that should apply to and the desired price

You can find more information in https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/catalog/pricing-advanced.html

if you dont want to update all products manually you can use csv as described [here](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/system/data-advanced-price.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't resolve my issue.